# Could not load Custom Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have created my own custom membership provider and referenced it in the `web.config` as follows

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="HelpDeskSupport.App_Code.MyMembershipProvider, HelpDeskSupport.App_code"
         cacheTimeoutInMinutes="30"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

However whenever I run the project it complains `Could not load file or assembly 'HelpDeskSupport.App_code' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have checked the root folder and everything checks out, here is a snapshot of the folder structure

[image: snapshot]

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part in the `type` element has to be just the assembly name:

```
type="HelpDeskSupport.App_Code.MyMembershipProvider, HelpDeskSupport"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I am getting a slightly different error `Could not load type 'HelpDeskSupport.App_Code.MyMembershipProvider' from assembly 'HelpDeskSupport'.`

Comment: Fixed the issue now. Renamed the folder and changed it in web.config. Confusing how the folder name caused the issue?